# Revert committed files to their version in master?

Tags: git, git-revert

I modified a number of files and committed my changes.

I have noticed that there are 3 files that I shouldn't have modified, and I want them to go back to being what they were in master, but I don't want to reset to a previous commit because I don't want my other file changes being lost. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did **not push yet** so your commit is only local for now, a simple process would be

```
# restore these 3 files to their previous state
git checkout HEAD^ -- path/to/file1 path/to/file2 path/to/file3

# include these changes...
git add path/to/file1 path/to/file2 path/to/file3

# ... in last commit
git commit --amend
```

---

However, if you did **already push**, there are 2 basic scenarios :

1) **Either** you work alone on this repo, or share the repo but work alone on this branch (oftentimes the case for feature branches, but depends on your workflow)

The above process is fine, just be aware that the next time you'll want to push to the remote, you'll have to use the `-f` flag in your push command to force-update the old ref.

2) **or** this is a shared branch, its history can't be changed without some amount of trouble

Then the process above, rewriting history, is to be avoided. Instead, you'll just have to omit the `--amend` parameter at the end, and it'll make a new commit which contains only this last modification of your files. Less elegant than commiting it right in the first place but you did not change history and your files are fine.